# Esscher Transform extended

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

**This problem is almost solved, dont get scared by the massive text**

The Esscher-transform is a well know tool in the financial section.
I posted this in statistics also, since it relates to continuous sampling.
Im not sure if my approach is right, so it would be nice, if someone could check this.

Given a Levy-process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ under $P$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ Let be $u$ be real such that the cumulant generating function of $X_t$ given by $\phi_{t}(u)=log(E[exp(uX_t)])$ is finite. We have with levy-properties $\phi_{t}(u)=t\phi_{1}(u)$.

We know that the Esscher-transform

$$
Z_{t}=e^{uX_t-t\phi_{1}(u)} \tag 1
$$
is a positive Martingale wrt to $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$ and this density defines a measure $Q|\mathcal{F}_t$. We can define a measure $Q$ (by extension for $t\rightarrow \infty$) under which $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is again a Levyprocess and its density on $\mathcal{F}_t$ is given by
$$
\frac{dQ}{dP}|_{\mathcal{F}_t}=\frac{dQ}{dP}((X_{s})_{0\leq s \leq t})=Z_{t} 
$$

Now however the restirction of $dQ/dP$ on $\mathcal{F}_t$ first says that $Z_t$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable function and can thus be expressed almost surely as an function of the sample path $(X_s)_{s\leq t}$. Like in sequential statistics, we observe on $[0,t]$ and the induced likelihood-ratio $Z_t$ depends on the process observed on this interval.

**I want the understanding, why one says, that the induced measure $Z_t$ of the trajectory $(X_s)_{s\leq t}$ is only a function of the last $X_t$.
So i want an understanding how we get this expression of $Z_t$.**
Typically in my understanding one has first to construct $Z_t$ in a common sense
$$
Z_{t}=e^{\int_{0}^{t}udX_s-\int_{0}^{t}\phi_{1}(u)ds} \tag 2
$$
where you literally see, that the density is really a function of $(X_s)_{s\leq t}$, but which in the end really coincides with (1) then. This connects to my 2nd approach.

There are possibly  approaches:

Maybe since the cumulant generating function of $X_t$ $\phi_t$ is $t\cdot \phi_1$. So that the one dimensional distribution of $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ totally determine the law of the process, such that $X_t$ is enough to describe?

First approach: This is not so clear for me. Maybe one can help me here. Maybe one can argue with the bayes forumla of conditional expectation, since the density process $Z_{t}$ is a Martingale wrt to $\mathcal{F}_t$ or general by the conditional expectation.
Where for the second assertion we have for $s<t$ that
$$
E_{Q}[Z_{t}|\mathcal{F}_s]=e^{uX_s-s\phi_1(u)}=Z_s
$$
or for $A \in \mathcal{F}_s$
$$
Q_{|\mathcal{F}_t}(A)=E_{P}[L_t 1_{A}]=E_{P}[E_{P}[L_t 1_A|\mathcal{F_s}]=E_{P}[L_s 1_A]=Q_{|\mathcal{F}_s}(A)
$$
which states, that the measures are consistent.

Second approach:
We construct (2). But i dont know if the way is correct.

We know that the induced measure of a path $(X_s)_{s\leq t}$, is generated by its finite dimensional distributions.
Basawa "Statistical inference for Stochastic Processes" p. 181 recommends to calculate the finite dimensional distributions  of $X=(X_{t_0},X_{t_1},\ldots X_{t_n})$ for $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=t$ and let $\max_{1\leq i \leq n} t_i -t_{i-1}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

For a sequece $K_{i}$ of independent random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ with finite mean we have with $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}K_{i}$
$$
Z_n=\frac{e^{uS_n}}{E[e^{uS_n}]}
$$
Where $Z_{n}$ can be regarded as the density of the $n$-times product space wrt to $P^{\otimes n}$ and $Z_{n}=\prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{uK_{i}}/[Ee^{uK_{i}}]$
on $(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \Omega ,\otimes_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{F})$.

Lets $(K_{1},\ldots,K_{n})=(X_{t_1}-X_0(=0),X_{t_2}-X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}})$ the increments of the increments of the levy process.
Then
$$
Z_n=e^{(uS_{n})-t_1\phi_{1}(u)-(t_2-t_1)\phi_{1}(u)-\ldots (t_n-t_{n-1})\phi_{1}(u)}
$$
Letting $\max_{1\leq i \leq n} t_i -t_{i-1}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we can conclude (2).

The law of $(X_s)_{s\leq t}$ is completely determined by the law of finite dimensional distributions. $Z_{t}$ is generated by sampling the increments on $[0,t]$. Since $X_t$ is Markov, the finite dimensional distribution is the product of the incremental densitys. This should show (2) i hope?